# Using Core data with Core Plot

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, core-plot

I want to create graph that uses data retrieved from Core Data. I have been trying to look for a simple tutorial that I can follow to get an understanding on how to do this, but I have had no luck.

Does anyone know any tutorials or can guide me on how can I start building my graph from Core Data?

Answer (score 0):

Just read the data you need from Core Data, put them in the right format for Core Plot, and tell Core Plot to, well, plot.

For example, if you need to feed an array of numbers to `numbersForPlot`, extract the series from your managed objects and pass that array to this method.

Comment: Do you know any resources I can use to atleast start building a graph? Im having problems starting up.

Comment: That is a very broad question. If you are struggling with Core Plot, look at the provided sample code on Github. If you are struggling with Core Data,  you should find Core Data tutorials of which there are many.